# Export data from object

Tags: php, object

I have got object in symphony with `echo var_dump($tt);` gives me:

```
object(PropelObjectCollection)#635 (4) {
  ["model":protected]=>
  string(32) "Style\ModelBundle\Model\Company"
  ["iterator":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["formatter":protected]=>
  object(PropelObjectFormatter)#634 (9) {
    ["collectionName":protected]=>
    string(22) "PropelObjectCollection"
  }
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Style\ModelBundle\Model\Company)#636 (69) {
      ["startCopy":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["id":protected]=>
      int(2278701)
      ["name":protected]=>
      string(26) "xxx"
      ["modifiedColumns":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["virtualColumns":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get from that 'name' variable?

I was trying `"$tt->storage->{'name'}"`

but it's not working so mayby someone will give me a clue?